# Writing generalized hypergeometric function ${_nF}_{n-1}(\cdot)$ as a function of $n$

Tags: function-construction, special-functions

How can we code the hypergeometric function
$$
f(n,k,z)={_nF}_{n-1}{\huge(}{1-k,\overbrace{2,\dots,2}^{n-1\ \text{times}} \atop \underbrace{1,\dots,1}_{n-1\ \text{times}}};z{\huge)}
$$
as a function that accepts any $n=1,2,3,\dots$?  This function reduces to a rational function in $z$ but that is not what I'm after.  I apologize for lack of an attempt here...did not have any idea where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
aaronF[n_Integer?Positive, k_, z_] :=
  HypergeometricPFQ[Prepend[ConstantArray[2, n - 1], 1 - k], ConstantArray[1, n - 1], z]
```

For example:

```
aaronF[5, 4, z]
   1 - 48 z + 243 z^2 - 256 z^3
```

Comment: @JM Thank you.  Exactly what I was looking for.